# Find volume using double integral but symmetry to xy plane

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, derivatives, multiple-integral

$V=\{(x,y,z)\in R^3\mid x^2+y^2\le1, x^2+z^2\le1\}
$ find the volume 
Here i was confused why i need to multiply the double integral with 2? 
It is said that because it is symmetry to $xy$ plane? But i dont understand when i find problem like this whether i have to multiply it by 2 or not? Should i draw? And also it is a bit hard to draw in $xyz$ plane, is there another way to know whether i should multiply by two or not?
$z=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ $2 \int \int_D \sqrt{1-x^2}\; dx \; dy$, where i need to multiply it by two???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** First draw what the first condition says: $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$ is a disk, and $z$ is arbitrary, so this is a cylinder that runs along the $z$-axis, whereas the latter condition gives a cylinder along the $y$ axis. The two conditions together then provide the volume of two intersected cylinders.

There is a vizualization [here](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/cylinders/)

The solid is known as the [steinmetz solid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteinmetzSolid.html).

One can re-write the coniditions as saying that $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$ while $-\sqrt{1-x^2} \leq z \leq \sqrt{1-x^2}$ so we get

$$\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}1 dz \, dy\,dx=2 \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\sqrt{1-x^2}  dy\,dx=4\int_{-1}^{1}1-x^2 dx.$$

Comment: thanks i can picture it but i didnt understand why $2 \int \int_D \sqrt{1-x^2}\; dx \; dy$, i need to multiply this by two??

Comment: in xyz plane is this a formula?? to multiply it by two?

Comment: I added some detail.

Comment: The first equality should be what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks!!!! so 2 come from triple integral, from dz? and is it possible to evaluate this using cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: Yes, and yes. Some googling should give results

Comment: i tried ,  $2 \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1   \sqrt{1-r^2 cos \theta}\; rdr \; d\theta$ is it true? but i think it is better not to use this, because it is hard to do the integration for $dr$ ?